# Personal loan from Dubai to send to India

Tags: taxes, india, personal-loan, dubai

I am staying in Dubai and I am planning to take a personal loan of INR 10 lacs. I would be using it to purchase a car back in India.

Do I have to pay tax for this? if yes, is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a personal loan in Dubai and transfer the funds into NRE account in India and purchase a car. There is no taxes for this in India.